# error in getting the output of a stored procedure

Tags: c#, resharper

I am trying to get the output of a stored procedure into a function but with my code i am always getting a error telling that the output parameter is not specified.Can u help?

the code is here.....

```
public int UserAuthentication(String username, String password)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=...\\..; Initial Catalog=CUSTOMER360;User ID=sa;password=******");
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_Campaign_UserAuthentication", conn);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@login_id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "loginid"));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password",
        SqlDbType.VarChar,50,
        "password"));
    SqlParameter ret = command.Parameters.Add(" @result", SqlDbType.Int);
    ret.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
    command.Parameters["@login_id"].Value = username;
    command.Parameters["@password"].Value = password;
    conn.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    return (int)ret.Value;
}
```

Comment: I assume that the sa user password you've posted is a dummy string?  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the ReturnValue parameter has to be the first in the *(edit) command* parameter list.

Also, try querying the return parameter's value before closing the connection.

Ensure that your stored proc calls

```
RETURN (@SomeReturnValue)
```

Lastly, try removing the leading space in your " @result" parameter name, just in case.

Comment: @result is the return value and it is in the parameter list.And i also have tried to get the return value before closing the connection but the result is same.........

Comment: Your code has the parameter as the third parameter added to the command's parameter list. Move it as the first.

Comment: Can you please post the header of the stored procedure as well? Just the proc name and parameter list will do. I wonder if you've mixed up Output and ReturnValue parameter types.

Comment: i found the solution its a store procedure so not a return type ParameterDirection.output; has to be used